# Errors in my Android Project

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have many errors in my project.Please help me to fix the errors!

The errors are mostly in brackets. I have an file where the errors as resoirces listed is. The name of the file is: public.xml in the values folder.

I have Android Studio 1.0.1 on Windows 8

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(//**error here*/0x7f030000);
}

private void fillInFingerprint() {
    fingerprint = new ArrayList(0x4);
    fingerprint.add(new BasicNameValuePair("model", Build.MODEL));
    fingerprint.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fingerprint", Build.FINGERPRINT));
    fingerprint.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hardware", Build.HARDWARE));
    fingerprint.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serial", Build.SERIAL));
    fingerprint.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kernel", javaSucksAssReadTheKernelVersion()));
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    String nonce = new BigInteger(0x40, random).toString(0x20);
    fingerprint.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nonce", nonce));
    fingerprint.add(new BasicNameValuePair("appversion", getSoftwareVersion()));
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(//**error here*/0x7f050003);
    String modstring = et.getText().toString();
    fingerprint.add(new BasicNameValuePair("modstring", modstring));
}

private String queryServer(String reportType) {
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://gettings.appspot.com/report/" + reportType);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(fingerprint));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        return new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
    } catch(ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.i("gettings_java", "got ClientProtocolException");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.i("gettings_java", "got IOException");
    }
    return "";
}

public void titleClicked(View view) {
    Log.i("gettings_java", "title clicked");
    tclick = (tclick + 0x1);
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(//**error here*/0x7f050003);
    if((tclick >= 0x3) && (!didrun)) {
        et.setVisibility(0x0);
        et.setText("1337 0 1 0 4 0");
    }
}

public void buttonClicked(View view) {
    if(!didrun) {
        fillInFingerprint();
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(//**error here*/0x7f050002);
        String responseString = queryServer("initial");
        if(responseString.equals("")) {
            tv.setText("Please ensure you are connected to the internet");
            return;
```

Greetings from Germany

Comment: You code is not finished. At least post entire functions for us to help you... What does your IDE or compiler say?

Comment: How can we help you unless you tell us what is the error?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i have this remark in the code //**error here*/

Comment: Seems your editor is not generating the R file, which is required.

Comment: javaSucksAssReadTheKernelVersion() <== I love to find this type of things when reading code :)

Comment: This is towelroot's source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously , you have errors when you try to load a variable from R. That means that we have two candidates from your problem.

a. You have an error in your xml files (layouts-values or everything) and you have to correct this error in order to complete the built successfully.

b. You have to import at this java file your project.R

> import your_project_name.R;

Comment: I have only errors in this Java file. I have imported your code but the imput line is grey.

Answer (score 1):

The locations you marked with errors are all places where you seem to be trying to find Views using literal ID values.

You should never use a literal value (e.g. `300` or `0x7f050002`) to reference resources such as View IDs. All generated resource identifiers such as View IDs can change every time you compile.

Instead you should be using the `R` class. For example, if you create a View with `android:id="@+id/my_view_id`, you should reference it in code with `R.id.my_view_id`. This will ensure that your ID references are always correct.

`R` should be generated every time you compile, and should be created under your app's package name.